# BigQuery: Find users that are not updating data consecutively for more than 2 months

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a big query table with 2 fields of concern:

| ID | Date |
| --- | --- |
| Q123 | 2021-06-14 13:12:30.000000 UTC |
| A456 | 2021-09-29 10:06:20.000000 UTC |
| A456 | 2021-08-30 10:53:14.000000 UTC |
| A456 | 2023-05-30 10:02:30.000000 UTC |
| Q123 | 2022-06-13 12:03:53.000000 UTC |
| Q123 | 2021-07-20 10:00:04.000000 UTC |
| A456 | 2021-09-29 10:06:20.000000 UTC |

I want to find out if any of the users (ID) has not made an entry in the table for consecutive 2 months. I do not have a partitioned table but a singular one.

I am not a novice but I am unable to write anything that is helping me in this scenario. Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of BigQuery's window function LAG to get the previous date for each ID and then calculate the difference between dates in months. If the difference is greater than or equal to 2 months, you can select those rows. Here is a sample query that demonstrates this:

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT ID, Date,
    DATE_DIFF(
      Date, 
      LAG(Date) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date), 
      MONTH
    ) AS months_diff
  FROM your_table
)
SELECT *
FROM data
WHERE months_diff >= 2
```

This query will first calculate the difference in months between each date and the previous date (for the same ID) and will return the rows where the difference is 2 months or more.

Remember that in BigQuery, the LAG function treats each partition separately. So, the LAG(Date) in one partition won't affect LAG(Date) in another partition.

Please replace your_table with your actual table name.

Also note that this would only consider entries that are present in the data. If a user hasn't made any entries at all for a period of two or more months, you would need a different approach that involves generating a series of dates and checking for the existence of entries for each user on each date.

Comment: This is super helpful, thanks. I created a new table where the date column is of format date instead of timestamp since the original table was giving an error:                                 
 Query error: DATE_DIFF does not support the MONTH date part when the argument is TIMESTAMP type at [15:5].